# Streaming a Java collection returned directly from function

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a Java data structure that contains a list List<Foo<Map<String, String>>>.

I would like to stream this collection without having to re-declare the list. Is there a way this can be done with Streams?

Ex Works:

```
List<Foo<Map<String, String>>> list = my_data_structure.getListOfFoo();
list.stream().forEach(map -> map.keySet())
```

Ex Does not work

```
my_data_structure.getListOfFoo().stream().forEach(map -> map.keySet())
```

The above doesnt work because instead of thinking of each entry in the string as a map it interprets it as an Object and therefore wont compile.

```
public class my_data_struct()
   private List<Foo<Map<String, Object>>> foo;       

   public List<Foo<Map<String, String>>> getListOfFoo() {
      return this.foo;
   }
```

Comment: what's the return type of `getListOfFoo`?

Comment: What is the error message? And please show how `my_data_structure.getListOfFoo` is declared. Is it a generic method?

Comment: Edited to include the getter for foo. It is not a generic method is explicitly cast

Comment: Your `my_data_struct` class does not compile. Please show a [mcve].

Answer (score 3):

Calling stream on `List<Foo<Map<String, String>>>` will return a stream of `Foo`, not a stream of `Map<String, String>` directly. It's not possible that the first example you gave works unless the `Foo` class has a `keySet` method.

You need to do `my_data_structure.getListOfFoo().stream().forEach(foo -> foo.map().keySet())` where `Foo::map` would return the inner map.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have field of type Map in Foo Class

```
public class Foo {
    private Map<String, String> myMap;
    
    public Map<String, String> getMap(){
        return myMap;
    }
}
```

Correct syntax for

```
List<Foo> list = my_data_structure.getListOfFoo();
```

After this, you should be able to get the required result.

Comment: But there is nothing wrong with declaring a generic version of `Foo`

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility.  Since you are getting all the keys to all the maps, I put them in a Set to eliminate duplicates.

First, build some test data.

```
Map<String, String> map1 =
        Map.of("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C");
Map<String, String> map2 =
        Map.of("A", "A", "D", "D", "C", "C", "E", "E");

record Foo<T extends Map<?,?>>(T getMap){}

List<Foo<Map<String,String>>> my_data_structure =
               List.of(new Foo<>(map1), new Foo<>(map2));
```

- Then stream the list of Foo and flatten the keysets to one stream.
- Then collect them into a set.

```
Set<String> keys = my_data_structure.stream()
        .flatMap(foo -> foo.getMap().keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
System.out.println(keys);
```

Prints

```
[A, B, C, D, E]
```

If you collect them into a list you would get something like this (the order may be different).

```
[A, B, C, E, A, C, D]
```

Note:  The fact that the `Set` is in sorted order is happenstance.  Set's are unordered data structures.